# How do i stop a timer when i set a game to paused

Tags: python-3.x, time, pygame

I have created this game which gives you a time limit to kill as many as the targets as you can. Below is the part of the code which pauses and unpauses the game. The problem I am having is that when I pause the game the timer which sets the time limit is still counting. How do I get this to stop?

```
paused = False

def button(msg, msg_two, x, y, w, h, i, a, fontsize,  action=None):
    global paused
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if  (x < mouse[0] < (x+450)) and (y < mouse[1]<(y+100)):
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, a, [x, y, w, h])
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',fontsize)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(msg, largeText, green)
        TextRect.center = ((x+(w/2)),(y+(h/2)))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "play":
                gameloop()
            elif action == "quit":
                game_quit()
            elif action == "pause":
                paused = True
                pause()
            elif action == "unpause":
                unpause()

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, i, [x, y, w, h])
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',fontsize)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(msg_two, largeText, green)
        TextRect.center = ((x+(w/2)),(y+(h/2)))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

def game_quit():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def unpause():
    global paused
    paused = False

def pause():

    pygame.mouse.set_visible(1)

    button_x = (display_width/4)-150
    button_y = display_height/1.5
    button_width = 450
    button_height = 100


    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()


        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',72)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects('paused', largeText, red)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/3))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        button("let's go", "carry on", button_x, button_y, button_width, button_height, blue, light_blue, 70,  "unpause")
        button("Bye then :(", "Leaving?", button_x+600, button_y, button_width, button_height, red, light_red, 70,  "quit")

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def gameloop():

    gameExit = False

    start = time.time()

    elapsed = 0

    while not gameExit and elapsed < 30:
        button("Stop", "Stop", 1550, 0, 50, 50, red, light_red, 15, "pause")
        elapsed = time.time() - start - (enemy_kills/2)
    gameloop()

def game_intro():
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(1)

    button_x = (display_width/4)-150
    button_y = display_height/1.5
    button_width = 450
    button_height = 100

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()


        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',72)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects('Shoot Hitler and not trump', largeText, red)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/3))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        button("let's go", "wanna play?", button_x, button_y, button_width, button_height, blue, light_blue, 70,  "play")
        button("Bye then :(", "wanna quit?", button_x+600, button_y, button_width, button_height, red, light_red, 70,  "quit")

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

game_intro()
```

I apologize if I have missed out important parts of the code. Inform me if I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other strange things in this program that makes it hard to understand it enough to give you a proper answer.

For example, the fact that you call back `gameloop()` at the end of the `gameloop` function - it creates a recursive call that should no t be recursive at all.

Anyway, what happens is that you should move most of these functions inside a class - so that some of the state variables like `paused` can be an attribute of that class. Instances of the class are meant to be game plays.

In that case, your "start"  variable would be made an attribute as well, so that it could be modified from within the `unpause` method.

You then could count the amount of paused time, and add that amount to the  "start" tick count  .

Or you can just make `start` a global variable and go on with your current pattern.  Since I am not re-organizng all of your code just to answer the question, keeping the things more or less as they are would require you to do:

```
def gameloop():
    global start
    ...

def pause():
   global pause_start
   pause_start = time.time()
   ...

def unpause():
   global start, pause_start
   pause_duration = time.time() - pause_start
   start += pause_duration
   ...
```